# Creating a Stick man with rectangular sticks

Tags: modeling, rigging

I tried creating a stickman rig with rectangular sticks. For easier understanding, this is what I have so far:

[image]

The Problem with it is, that I just used rectangular object and added some caps to them. Than I strapped each element via an empty to a bone. During render though I found out that Blender Render cannot render overlapping faces.

**-> how would I go about modeling such a model without overlapping surfaces?**

This is my first Blender creation, that's why I tried picking the simplest way to do things, as it is also the only way I know how to do it.

Thank you very much for helping me out :D

Comment: The simplest solution would be to avoid overlap by moving one of the two geometry slightly above the other. On the other side, you could also deform the meshes with shapekeys or something like that, it all depends on your project's goal. I think you should describe better your situation.

Comment: Blender can render overlapping faces, however they will overlap (quite obviously) which will cause z-fighting. If you'd like to bend that object on the table then you can use either Curve modifier and add a curve of adjacent form, or add an armature for the object and rig it somehow (bone envelopes or vertex groups).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a single mesh instead of many small overlapping ones.

Start with a cube.
[image]

Then press "Tab" to go into edit mode
Then press "Ctrl + Tab" and select "Face"
Right click the top of the cube, press "G" then middle mouse button
then pull up, then right click

I can go on and on, email me at psuheena@yahoo.com
and we can set up a teamviewer so I can show you one on one if you want.

[[image]]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJJd9.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) So I would extrude a few times where my joints are going to be so they bend nicely? And then I can add the skin modifier? Is this the direction I have to go towards? If yes, I'll search for tutorials and try figuring it out over the weekend, but thank you very very much for your graciously offer :D I might come back to your offer, but I think it's best if I don't waste your time and find a solution myself :)

Comment: I have time today, right now. If you download teamviewer, we can make it happen today

Comment: I was thinking of extruding the base cube, giving it loop cuts, then rigging it with bones. Give it some basic color and maybe a subsurf modifier if that is the look you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the offer once again :D I was busy over the week but have now found some time to get in working. I made the center body in 1 mesh and deform it with envelopes, the lower arms/legs as separate meshes (as I had it before), but scaled in 2 Dimensions. If you're interested in how it turns out, you can go to my Youtube Channel (birawaich), I'll upload the final animation there. There's not a whole lot going on there ATM, but I'm starting to understand blender now :) Thanks again :)

Comment: I think the hardest part of animation is the lighting. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1R1z9ipFnM

Comment: Thanks again for the help. My knowledge since posting this post has increased drastically and it's funny looking back seeing what I didn't know just a few months ago. Also, for lighting I started using Cycles, which looks way better, thanks for the hint!

Comment: glad to hear you made progress

Comment: So I finally found the upload button and the final animation can be found here [YouTube -> Me, online shopping.](https://youtu.be/bU82yiBeNdI). Just in case your interested ;) Thanks again for the help!